# Best option for transferring Euros into Indian NRE account?

Tags: india, foreign-exchange, money-transfer, non-resident

I have a bank account in EU in euros and want to remit some funds to my Indian NRE account. What is the most efficient way to remit the funds to my NRE account:

1. Which methods give the best currency rates?
2. Which methods are the quickest?
3. What the fees involved with different methods?

Searching around the internet gave me some commonly used services like money2india, hdfcremit, yes remit. Are there other services that will give me a better exchange rate? What services would be recommended?

Comment: There is no best method. Refer to other question for pros and cons. http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24594/how-does-remittance-work-how-does-it-differ-from-direct-money-transfer